# Visual Studio Error-XLS0509 - how to fix it? - XAML - Microsoft Tutorial

Tags: c#, winforms, xaml

I was following the tutorial from - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/getting-started/walkthrough-my-first-wpf-desktop-application?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8
**till the handle events section**
But I encountered at line 35 in this XAML code -**ERROR XLS0509**
Saying

> Error  XLS0509 Property elements cannot be in the middle of an element's content. They must be before or after the content.

```
<Page x:Class="ExpenseIt.ExpenseItHome"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ExpenseIt"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="350" d:DesignWidth="500"
  Title="ExpenseIt - Home">

<Grid Margin="10, 0, 10, 10">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="230" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
    <!--People List-->
    <Label Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Trebuchet MS" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18" Foreground="White">
        View Expense Report
    </Label>
    <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="35" Padding="5" Background="#FFD44E4E">
        <Label VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White">Names</Label>
    </Border>
    
    <!-- bg img-->
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="368.png"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <ListBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
        <ListBoxItem>Mike</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Lisa</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>John</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Mary</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
    
    <!-- View report Button -->
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Margin="0, 10, 0, 0" Width="125" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right">View</Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: The Page tag is not closed.  Add to end of file :  </Page>

Comment: Put that `<Grid.Background>...</Grid.Background>` somewhere above the first `<Label>`. It would be customary to put it before the `Grid.ColumnDefinitions`. The error is that you're mixing code which sets properties (that elements sets Grid's Background property) with code which sets the element's content (the `Label`, `Border` and `ListBox` are all part of the content)

Comment: If that fixes it, there's a "Feedback" section at the bottom of the page where you can report problems

Comment: Thanks canton7. It would be great if you could post that as an answer so I can accept it